# Why do I get a 500 error (undefined method 'to_model' on save of duplicated Ruby on Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm new to rails and still fuzzy on some things but here goes.

I am sending json post request to /microposts/10/duplicate.json to duplicate a micropost.

The route goes to microposts#duplicate

The Controller action is:

```
def duplicate
  micropost = current_user.microposts.find(params[:id])
  new_micropost = micropost.dup
  respond_with new_micropost.save
end
```

The server logs for the request is:

```
Started POST "/microposts/15/duplicate.json" for 180.181.247.76 at 2015-09-06 11:00:38 +0000
Processing by MicropostsController#duplicate as JSON
  Parameters: {"_json"=>15, "id"=>"15", "micropost"=>{}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Micropost Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = ? AND "microposts"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "microposts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 2], ["id", 15]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "microposts" ("content", "user_id", "title", "link", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "RLCPYIIG"], ["user_id", 2], ["title", "herp"], ["link", "snerp"], ["created_at", "2015-09-06 11:00:38.576553"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-06 11:00:38.576553"]]
   (11.7ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 12.8ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass):
  app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:23:in `duplicate'
```

So the micropost is saved but I don't know why I get the 500 error.
Also, should I be using .require and .permit here? The only thing in params from the front end should be the id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently getting a similar error when using `respond_with`.

Turned out I was just missing the corresponding view for my action when requesting a HTML response.

Unfortunately the error was rather cryptic with..

```
undefined method `to_model' for #<Array:0x007fc7c59ada50> Did you mean? to_xml
```

**TLDR:** *Check you have a corresponding view.*

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I should be using PUT not POST here.