# ajax not working on load more action in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Here is my blog_post_inner.js :\

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // when the load more link is clicked
$('a.load-more').click(function (e) {

    // prevent the default click action
    e.preventDefault();

    // hide load more link
    $('.load-more').hide();

    // show loading gif
    $('.loading-gif').show();

    // get the last id and save it in a variable 'last-id'
    var last_id = $('.record').last().attr('data-id');

    // make an ajax call passing along our last user id
    $.ajax({
        // make a get request to the server
        type: "GET",
        // get the url from the href attribute of our link
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        // send the last id to our rails app
        data: {
            id: last_id
        },
        // the response will be a script
        dataType: "script",

        // upon success 
        success: function () {
            // hide the loading gif
            $('.loading-gif').hide();
            // show our load more link
            $('.load-more').show();
        }
    });

 });
});
```

Inside blog_post_inner my main ajax is defined.

I am calling it here inside blog_post_inner.html.erb:

```
<div class="load-more-container">
    <!-- hide our loading gif image so that we show it when making ajax call via jquery -->
<%= image_tag "ajax-loader.gif", style: "display:none;", class: "loading-gif" %>
<%= link_to_next_page articles,"Load More" ,class: "load-more" %>
</div>
```

But the main problem is my ajax is not loading the page in the same webpage istead its reloading/refreshing/redirecting to second page.

What to do?

I have tried changing **link_to_next_page** to **link_to** but it's giving an  error:

> undefined method `to_model' for #
>   Did you mean?  to_xml

Please help my ajax is not working i have tried so many different methods but none of them prove to be useful.

I followed this article to implement this:
http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/rails-load-more-results-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422963/why-do-i-get-a-500-error-undefined-method-to-model-on-save-of-duplicated-ruby help?

Comment: I am looking on it thanks @kabanus

Comment: I have the view file,css file,js file,js.erb file all fine.Even js and css is loading to but ajax is not working.I am having doubt if ajax is right or not. @kabanus

Comment: I have checked it, the issue is same but in different cases.